# Thymeleaf form allow input if radio checked

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I wish to allow user to enter input in return date only if the radiobutton return is checked. I have uploaded my form below, please let me know if I have to add anything else. Also, how can I leave my radiobuttons unticked when user goes to the form for the first time?

```html
<div class = "col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label>Return date: </label> 
                    <Input type="date" th:field="*{returnDate}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label>Return </label>
                    <Input type="radio" th:field="*{flightReturn}"
                            th:value="true" />
                    <label>One-way </label>
                    <Input type="radio" th:field="*{flightReturn}"
                            th:value="false" />
                            </div>
```

Edit: used javascript and it helped

Comment: This is not related to `Spring` or `Thymeleaf`. You can simply use javascript or jquery to handle this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this easily with jQuery.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('.true-radio').click(function()
  {
    $('.date-input').removeAttr("disabled");
  });

  $('.false-radio').click(function()
  {
    $('.date-input').attr("disabled","disabled");
  });
});
</script>
```

Youll also need to add classes to your html:

```
<div class = "col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label>Return date: </label> 
                    <Input type="date" class="date-input" th:field="*{returnDate}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "col-sm-6 form-group">
                    <label>Return </label>
                    <Input class="true-radio" type="radio" th:field="*{flightReturn}"
                            th:value="true" />
                    <label>One-way </label>
                    <Input class="false-radio" type="radio" th:field="*{flightReturn}"
                            th:value="false" />
                            </div>
```

If you add all this code to your html it should work.